# Writing into a Jupyter Notebook from Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, streamwriter

Is it possible for a Python script to write into a iPython Notebook?

```py
with open("my_notebook.ipynb", "w") as jup:
     jup.write("print(\"Hello there!\")")
```

If there's some package for doing so, can I also control the way cells are split in the notebook?

I'm designing a software tool (that carries out some optimization) to prepare an iPython notebook that can be run on some server performing scientific computations.

I understand that a related solution is to output to a Python script and load it within a iPython Notebook using `%load my_python_script.py`. However, that involves a user to type stuff that I would ideally like to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [nbformat](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat) repo on Github. The reference implementation is shown there.

From their [docs](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-nbformat.v4)

> Jupyter (né IPython) notebook files are simple JSON documents, containing text, source code, rich media output, and metadata. Each segment of the document is stored in a cell.

It also sounds like you want to create the notebook programmatically, so you should use the `NotebookNode` object.

For the code, something like, should get you what you need. `new_cell_code` should be used if you have code cells versus just plain text cells. Text cells should use the existing markdown formatting.

```
import nbformat

notebook = nbformat.v4.new_notebook()


text = """Hello There """



notebook['cells'] = [nbformat.v4.new_markdown_cell(text)]
notebook= nbformat.v4.new_notebook()
nbformat.write(notebook,'filename.ipynb')
```